# How to get Hint and Text of a button In android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using this code to get the id of the button which is clicked and then use the id to get the text and hint of the same button
I don't know why but maybe this code this crashing the app after I use getID() method.
I am using Relative Layout.

The Java code

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

public AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
public AlertDialog dialog;
public EditText Name,Password;
public Button Save,Cancel,temp,ok,x;
public String file_location = "Passwords.txt";
public String name_x,pass_y;
public LinearLayout mylayout = null;
public RelativeLayout rl = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void View_Password(Button x){
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

};

public void NewPassword(){
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final View NewPassSaveView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.newpasspopup, null);

    Name = (EditText) NewPassSaveView.findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    Password = (EditText) NewPassSaveView.findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);

    Save = (Button) NewPassSaveView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Cancel = (Button) NewPassSaveView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    dialogBuilder.setView(NewPassSaveView);
    dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

   
    Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Name.getText().toString())) {
                Name.setError("This Field is compulsory");
                return;
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Password.getText().toString())) {
                Password.setError("This Field is compulsory");
                return;
            }
            rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Saving...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button temp = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            temp.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ));
            rl.addView(temp);
            temp.setText(Name.getText().toString());
            temp.setHint(Password.getText().toString());
            temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int btn_id = v.getId();
                    btn2string(btn_id);
                }
            });
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

public void AddNew(View view) {
    NewPassword();
}


public void btn2string(int x){
    Button btn = findViewById(x);
    name_x = btn.getText().toString();
    pass_y = btn.getHint().toString();
    See_Password(name_x,pass_y);
}

public void See_Password(String name,String pass){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: "+name+"\n"+"Password: "+pass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

//The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/heading"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="319dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Password Manager"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.051" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:onClick="AddNew"
    android:text="Add new"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.973" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="366dp"
    android:layout_height="541dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please tell if there is any other way to do this or tell the mistakes in the above code so that I can get the hint and text of that button which is clicked...

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside,

> NewPassword()

method just change the following code.

```
public void NewPassword(){
 ......
 save.setOnClickListener(...){
    ........
    temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
          int btn_id = v.getId(); // remove this line.
          btn2String(temp);  //directly pass temp i.e. Button you created. 
         }
     });
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
  });
 ..........
}
```

And, pass Button type as a parameter in btn2String() method. as below:

```
public void btn2String(Button x){
  Button btn  = findViewById(x); // remove this line of code.
  name_x = x.getText().toString();
  pass_y = x.getHint().toString();
  See_Password(name_x, pass_y);
}
```

Comment: actually I need to pass the button which is clicked ,that button as the parameter in btn2string function if I would pass temp as the parameter it will take the most recently created button. Can I pass "this" as the parameter anyhow to pass the the button which is clicked???

Comment: no, you can't pass 'this' and as per your code, you will be creating only one button and if you try to create a new button it will be replaced by the recent one.

Comment: thanks brother I figured it out                                                                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                        Button btn_clicked = (Button)v;
                        btn2string(btn_clicked);
                    }                                                                                                                                 I had to use it like this  by the way the buttons are not saving I mean when I reopen the app I can't see the old ones how can I save them will OnsavedInstance and OnRestoreInstance  work here ??

Comment: In order to save the button even after closing your app, you need to use shared preference or room database, or sqlite.

Comment: if this helps you, please upvote/accept this as the answer.